# Join two tables plus pivot table as a stored-procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to make a order procedure on MySQL to make a pivot table as a result, but it is really complicated and I've no clue how to do it, I don't know if there is another way to do it more easy.

I need to get how many products has been bought in specifics addresses, result of GROUP_CONCAT(ship_addr + ship_zip + ship_contry).

**Order table** - Containing the order address.

```
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+
| id |   ship_addr    | ship_zip | ship_country |
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+
|  1 | Addr1          |  123     |           DE |
|  2 | Addr2          |  321     |           DE |
|  3 | Addr1          |  123     |           DE |
|  4 | Addr2          |  321     |           DE |
|  5 | Addr3          |  543     |           DE |
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+
```

**Order positions table**

```
+----+---------------+------------+--------------+
| id |   order_id    | product_id | quantity     |
+----+----------------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 1             |  1         |            5 |
|  2 | 1             |  2         |           10 |
|  3 | 2             |  3         |            5 |
|  4 | 3             |  1         |            5 |
|  5 | 4             |  1         |           10 |
|  6 | 5             |  1         |           10 |
+----+----------------+----------+---------------+
```

The expected result, column headers are product_id:

```
+-----------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Address        |   1   |   2   |   3   | 
+-----------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Addr1, 123, DE | 10    |  10   |     0 |
|  Addr2, 321, DE | 10    |  0    |     5 |
|  Addr3, 543, DE | 10    |  0    |     0 |
+-----------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I can't copy the store procedures I tried because they are completely failures.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone can edit the title because I don't know how to explain it better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  I come up with this solution just one part is missing to replace null with zero . i will try when I hot more time but the result is as per your expectation. Attached the out put as well . here it is worth to mention that the pivoted column needs ie(product_id) to be added statically . If you want then you can created a dynamic query to accommodated these pivoted columns as well .
Since it is taged with sql-server my answer is from SQL Server syntax .

```
        declare @order as table (
        id int , ship_addr varchar(100),ship_zip varchar(100) , ship_country varchar(100)
        )

        insert into @order (id,ship_addr,ship_zip,ship_country) values (1,'Add1','123','DE')
        insert into @order (id,ship_addr,ship_zip,ship_country) values (2,'Add2','321','DE')
        insert into @order (id,ship_addr,ship_zip,ship_country) values (3,'Add1','123','DE')
        insert into @order (id,ship_addr,ship_zip,ship_country) values (4,'Add2','321','DE')
        insert into @order (id,ship_addr,ship_zip,ship_country) values (5,'Add3','543','DE')

        declare @orderposition as table (
        id int , order_id int ,product_id int , quantity int
        )

        insert into @orderposition (id,order_id,product_id,quantity) values (1,1,1,5)
        insert into @orderposition (id,order_id,product_id,quantity) values (2,1,2,10)
        insert into @orderposition (id,order_id,product_id,quantity) values (3,2,3,5)
        insert into @orderposition (id,order_id,product_id,quantity) values (4,3,1,5)
        insert into @orderposition (id,order_id,product_id,quantity) values (5,4,1,10)
        insert into @orderposition (id,order_id,product_id,quantity) values (6,5,1,10)

        select  pvt.fulladd as Address , ISNULL([1],0) as [1] , ISNULL([2],0) as [2] , ISNULL([3],0) as [3]  from 
        (select fulladd, product_id , sum( isnull( quantity,0)) as qty from (
        select (o.ship_addr +' , ' + o.ship_zip +' ,' + o.ship_country) as fulladd , o.id from @order o
        ) as o
        inner join @orderposition p on p.order_id= o.id
        group by  fulladd, p.product_id
        ) as final



        pivot 
        (
           max(qty)  for product_id in ([1],[2],[3])

        ) as pvt
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I updated the null check as well please check my updated answer . I hope this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Possibly a good answer for sql server but mysql does not support table variables, or pivot.

Answer (score 1):

```
    with cte as (
    select t1.product_id, sum(t1.quantity) as quantity, t2.addr from order_positions t1 
    inner join (select id, ship_addr+', '+convert(varchar,ship_zip)+', '+ship_country as addr from order) t2 
    on t2.id = t1.order_id group by t2.addr, t1.product_id )
    select addr, isnull([1],0), isnull([2],0),isnull([3],0) from cte 
    pivot (sum(quantity) for [product_id] in ([1],[2],[3])) as pivottable
```

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: The select statement on third line gives you complete address that you need. so with common table expression, sum aggregate of quantity is calculated grouping by address and product id. The last statement is just pivot to get the result in your format. I hope this comment clears you.

Comment: Possibly a good answer for sql server but mysql does not support with or pivot statements.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is using group aggregation - note if you have more products you may need to invoke dynamic sql.

```
select concat(ship_addr,char(44),ship_zip,char(44),ship_country) address,
            sum(case when product_id = 1 then quantity else 0 end) as p1,
            sum(case when product_id = 2 then quantity else 0 end) as p2,
            sum(case when product_id = 3 then quantity else 0 end) as p3
    from    orderaddress oa
    join    orderposition op 
    where op.order_id = oa.id
    group by ship_addr,ship_zip,ship_country
```

Comment: The problem is I need to take the product_id on a dynamic way.